# Updating automatically QTableView after clicking buttons

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

I'm developing a simple program to create an attendance sheet for my job; I created the GUI with Qt Designer, and up to this point everything worked just fine, then I started coding the logic of the program. No matter what I tried, if I click on the buttons for punching in or out the system updates the data, but QTableView only updates if I click on it, while the button for creating a new month crashes the system; also, for whatever reason, sometimes the punch in button crashes the system as well. I tried to correct the setData() function using every possible piece of information I found online, but whatever the reason, nothing works and I don't know what to do.

This is the code:

```
import calendar
import datetime
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from attendance import Ui_MainWindow

def monthList():
    cal = calendar.Calendar()
    x = datetime.date.today()
    dayNames = ('LUN', 'MAR', 'MER', 'GIO', 'VEN', 'SAB', 'DOM')
    monthNames = ('GENNAIO', 'FEBBRAIO', 'MARZO', 'APRILE', 'MAGGIO', 'GIUGNO',
                  'LUGLIO', 'AGOSTO', 'SETTEMBRE', 'OTTOBRE', 'NOVEMBRE',
                  'DICEMBRE')
    monthList = []
    for i in cal.itermonthdays2(x.year, x.month):
        if i[0] != 0:
            day = dayNames[i[1]]
            date = datetime.date(x.year, x.month, i[0])
            monthList.append([day, date, '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''])
    month = monthNames[x.month-1] + ' ' + str(x.year)
    return month, monthList

class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super().__init__()
        self._data = data
        self.hheaders = ['Giorno', 'Data', 'In', 'Out', 'St. In', 'Str. Out',
                         'Ord.', 'Nott.', 'Str.', 'Str.nt.', 'Tot.', 'Note']

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            value = self._data[index.row()][index.column()]

            if isinstance(value, datetime.date):
                return value.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")

            return value

        if role == Qt.TextAlignmentRole:
            value = self._data[index.row()][index.column()]

            if isinstance(value, int) or isinstance(value, float):
                return Qt.AlignVCenter + Qt.AlignHCenter

        if role == Qt.ForegroundRole:
            value = self._data[index.row()][index.column()]

            if ((isinstance(value, int) or isinstance(value, float)) and
                value < 0):
                return QtGui.QColor('#ff0000')

    def setData(self, index, value, role=Qt.EditRole):
        if index.isValid():
            self._data.index[index.row()][index.column()] = value
            self.dataChanged.emit(index, index, (Qt.DisplayRole))
            return True
        return False

    def rowCount(self, index):
        return len(self._data)

    def columnCount(self, index):
        return len(self._data[0])

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole and orientation == Qt.Horizontal:
            return self.hheaders[section]
        if role == Qt.FontRole:
            font = QtGui.QFont()
            font.setBold(True)
            return QtCore.QVariant(font)
        return QtCore.QVariant()

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.month, self.data = monthList()
        self.ui.monthLabel.setText(self.month)

        self.model = TableModel(self.data)
        self.ui.attendanceTable.setModel(self.model)
        self.ui.attendanceTable.resizeColumnsToContents()
        self.ui.attendanceTable.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoSelection)
                
        self.ui.newMonthBtn.clicked.connect(self.new_month)
        self.ui.entryBtn.clicked.connect(self.punch_in)
        self.ui.exitBtn.clicked.connect(self.punch_out)
        
        self.show()

    def new_month(self):
        self.month, self.data = monthList()
        self.ui.monthLabel.setText(self.month)
        # missing line: I know there should be something here, but whatevere I put, it crashes the system
        
    def punch_in(self):
        for i in self.data:
            if i[1] == datetime.date.today():
                if i[2] != '':
                    dlg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox(self)
                    dlg.setWindowTitle("Dobbia timbratura")
                    dlg.setText("Hai già timbrato l'ingresso!")
                    button = dlg.exec_()
                    if button == QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Ok:
                        return None
                else:
                    x = datetime.datetime.now()
                    if x.minute > 45:
                        punchIn = str(x.hour + 1)
                    elif x.minute > 15 and x.minute < 30:
                        punchIn = str(x.hour + 0.3)
                    elif x.minute < 15:
                        punchIn = str(x.hour)
                    i[2] = punchIn

    def punch_out(self):
        for i in self.data:
            if i[1] == datetime.date.today():
                if i[2] == '':
                    dlg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox(self)
                    dlg.setWindowTitle("Mancata timbratura")
                    dlg.setText("Non hai ancora timbrato l'entrata!")
                    button = dlg.exec_()
                    if button == QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Ok:
                        return None
                elif i[3] != '':
                    dlg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox(self)
                    dlg.setWindowTitle("Dobbia timbratura")
                    dlg.setText("Hai già timbrato l'uscita!")
                    button = dlg.exec_()
                    if button == QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Ok:
                        return None
                else:
                    x = datetime.datetime.now()
                    if x.minute > 45:
                        punchOut = str(x.hour + 1)
                    elif x.minute > 15 and x.minute < 30:
                        punchOut = str(x.hour + 0.3)
                    elif x.minute < 15:
                        punchOut = str(x.hour)
                    i[3] = punchOut

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I didn't post the code I generated with pyuic5 for the GUI because it works, tell me if you need to see it and I'll edit my post.

Comment: Setting the values of `self.data` is not sufficient: how would the table know that the value have changed? That's why `dataChanged` (normally done within `setData()`) has to be emitted. The crash is probably caused by the fact that you're not considering all possibilities of `x.minute`, so `punchIn` may not be defined for values between 30 and 45 resulting in a `NameError`. In any case, if your IDE doesn't show a traceback for that (which is strange), just run the script in a terminal or prompt and you'll probably see the cause of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @musicamante about fixing punchIn(), can you please explain to me how to fix the other problem too? Because I tried with `self.model.setData(self.data)` and it doesn't work, and honestly I don't know what else to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main purpose of [`dataChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#dataChanged) is to notify any object attached to the model that the data has been modified and some action should be taken. Normally, this is what tells an item view to redraw its contents, so that it can reflect the visible value of the changed data for the given index (or index range).

Your main issue is that you are just updating the values in the list, but that doesn't notify the view about the change.

Since changes are done internally (not through editing of the view), you are not required to explicitly call `setData()` (and you probably don't even need implementing it if you don't intend to allow editing through the table UI), but `dataChanged` must still be emitted.

I strongly suggest you to carefully read the [Model/View Programming](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html) guide in order to better understand how the Model/View approach works in Qt (which is similar to the MVC pattern, but with some important differences).

Be aware that proper OOP demands that each object is responsible of its own actions (see [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)), so, while you could call `self.model.dataChanged()` externally, it's better to implement dedicated functions in the model class and do everything from there.

Note that there are other issues in your code, some are conceptual, other logical.

First of all, your punch in/out functions have three main problems:

- the `if/elif` blocks only consider less or greater values (no equality), and no checking in the range 30-45 is done, so, when the minute value is 15 or between 30 and 45 (included) no `punchIn` or `punchOut` variable is being created, raising a `NameError` exception and crashing your program (not the system, luckily!) as reported in your question;
- the `for` loop keeps iterating the whole list even when a matching date is found, which is wrong; in that case, a `break` should be used, to avoid further and unnecessary iterations;
- adding 1 to the hour may not be appropriate, as it could give ambiguous values: hours near midnight could easily result in 24 or 00, even if they are taken just a few seconds apart (23:59:59 and 00:00:01);

Then, you should use logic values for numeral entries (numbers, dates, times, etc), instead of string representations: you can always convert them to string whenever you need to export the data (e.g. CVS conversion), but using real value will make representation and management much more consistent (for instance, if you need to compute sums between cells).

Other issues:

- don't use QVariant unless you really know that you need it; PyQt automatically converts python types to C++/Qt types whenever required;
- if you want to prevent selection in a custom model, it's better to override the model's [`flag()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#flags) than changing the view's selection mode;
- calling `resizeColumnsToContents()` in an almost empty model is not a good idea; unless the model has *lots* of entries (in the order of thousands), if you want to be sure that the contents of each item are always visible, you should set the `ResizeToContents` section resize mode for the related header;
- unless you need custom behavior from a message box, prefer the [static functions](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html#static-public-members) of QMessageBox: there's no point in creating an instance for a basic text/title message box, and, since the default instance of QMessageBox only has the `Ok` button, there is no point in checking the pressed button;
- `return None` is redundant, since `None` is implicit in the standalone `return`; you may use that syntax for *code readability* in the context of a function that is expected to always return a value (including, but not exclusive to `None`), but it's pointless when it's just done to "quit" a function ("exit" its execution flow) that doesn't have a return value, like you did in `punch_in()` and `punch_out()`;
- it's usually better to call `show()` *outside* of the window class (or, at least, upon full initialization, so *never* in the `__init__` or any related call within it);
- è "Doppia", non "Dobbia" ;-)

In the following implementation I've changed the model in order to make it more self-contained (since the model clearly refers to a specific month, it's more logical to make the "month" value a part of it), and using [QDateTime](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html) based types to allow better Qt integration (including date/time representation and/or computation).

The `punch_in` and `punch_out` functions have related functions in the model, which will actually update the data if possible, and send back a return value depending on the success of the operation; the value is then used to eventually show a warning to the user.

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class TableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    hheaders = (
            'Giorno', 'Data', 'In', 'Out', 'St. In', 'Str. Out',
            'Ord.', 'Nott.', 'Str.', 'Str.nt.', 'Tot.', 'Note'
        )
    _columns = len(hheaders)

    def __init__(self, reference=None):
        if reference is None:
            reference = QDate.currentDate()
        super().__init__()

        self.month = QLocale().monthName(reference.month()).upper()

        first = QDate(reference.year(), reference.month(), 1)
        self._data = []
        for d in range(reference.daysInMonth()):
            date = first.addDays(d)
            self._data.append([
                date.toString('ddd').upper(), date, None, None, None, None, 
                '', '', '', '', '', ''
            ])

    def flags(self, index):
        return super().flags(index) & ~Qt.ItemIsSelectable

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid():
            return
            
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            value = self._data[index.row()][index.column()]
            if isinstance(value, QDate):
                return value.toString('dd/MM/yyyy')
            return value

        elif role == Qt.TextAlignmentRole:
            value = self._data[index.row()][index.column()]

            if isinstance(value, (int, float, QDate, QTime)):
                return Qt.AlignCenter

        elif role == Qt.ForegroundRole:
            value = self._data[index.row()][index.column()]

            if isinstance(value, (int, float)) and value < 0:
                return QColor('#ff0000')

    def rowCount(self, index):
        return len(self._data)

    def columnCount(self, index):
        return self._columns

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if orientation == Qt.Horizontal and role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self.hheaders[section]

        if role == Qt.FontRole:
            font = QFont()
            font.setBold(True)
            return font

    def dateIndex(self, query=None):
        if query is None:
            query = QDate.currentDate()
        for row, values in enumerate(self._data):
            if query == values[1]:
                return self.index(row, 0)
        return QModelIndex()

    def fixTime(self, time):
        value = QTime(time.hour(), 0)
        if time.minute() > 15:
            if time.minute() >= 45:
                delta = 3600
            else:
                delta = 1800
            value = value.addSecs(delta)
        return value

    def punchIn(self, when=None):
        '''
            Return values:
            -2: invalid date for this month
            0:  punch in already exists
            1:  success
        '''
        if when is None:
            when = QDateTime.currentDateTime()

        index = self.dateIndex(when.date())
        if not index.isValid():
            return -2

        values = self._data[index.row()]
        if values[2] is not None:
            return 0
        else:
            values[2] = self.fixTime(when.time())
            index = index.siblingAtColumn(2)
            self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
            return 1

    def punchOut(self, when=None):
        '''
            Return values:
            -2: invalid date for this month
            -1: no punch in yet
            0:  punch out already exists
            1: success
        '''
        if when is None:
            when = QDateTime.currentDateTime()

        index = self.dateIndex(when.date())
        if not index.isValid():
            return -2

        values = self._data[index.row()]
        if values[2] is None:
            return -1
        elif values[3] is not None:
            return 0
        else:
            values[3] = self.fixTime(when.time())
            index = index.siblingAtColumn(3)
            self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
            return 2


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.attendanceTable.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(
            QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)

        self.ui.newMonthBtn.clicked.connect(self.new_month)
        self.ui.entryBtn.clicked.connect(self.punch_in)
        self.ui.exitBtn.clicked.connect(self.punch_out)
        
        self.new_month()

    def new_month(self):
        self.model = TableModel()
        self.ui.monthLabel.setText(self.model.month)
        self.ui.attendanceTable.setModel(self.model)

    def punch_in(self):
        res = self.model.punchIn()
        if res == -2:
            QMessageBox.warning(self, 
                'Data non valida', 'Mese errato')
        elif res == 0:
            QMessageBox.warning(self, 
                'Doppia timbratura', 'Hai già timbrato l\'entrata!')
        self.ui.attendanceTable.scrollTo(self.model.dateIndex())

    def punch_out(self):
        res = self.model.punchOut()
        if res == -2:
            QMessageBox.warning(self, 
                'Data non valida', 'Mese errato')
        elif res == -1:
            QMessageBox.warning(self, 
                'Mancata timbratura', 'Non hai ancora timbrato l\'entrata!')
        elif res == 0:
            QMessageBox.warning(self, 
                'Doppia timbratura', 'Hai già timbrato l\'uscita!')
        self.ui.attendanceTable.scrollTo(self.model.dateIndex())


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Note, though, that a proper time table should probably use actual QDateTime values for the "punch in/out" (eventually adjusted to half hours) so that the total time can be properly computed (using [`secsTo()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#secsTo)).

Another issue, if you're working with night shifts, is that your current implementation always considers the *current* day, which will obviously create issues for the "punch out" for a night shift that starts before midnight and ends the day after; if that's your case, then you're facing a [common source of programmer headaches](https://xkcd.com/2867/): while you could easily add a further check in the `punchOut` to verify if the *previous* day has an incomplete shift, a further problem raises when night shifts start at the last day of the month, meaning that you cannot just work with day-of-month tables: a month table should probably include the last day of the previous month, any new month table should be created with unended shifts from the month before, and the previous table should be updated along with it.

And this does not even consider the problem of switching to and from Daylight Saving Time (winter/summer time). While QDateTime is normally able to deal with that, the problem can raise again whenever your country decides to stop those time changes (which [was almost decided for EU countries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summer_time_in_Europe#Future), but can still happen sooner or later).

Buona fortuna ;-)

Comment: WOW! I mean, this is so incredibly mind blowing it'll take me a lot just to understand the basics of what you're talking about, and then apply it to my model (which I'm currently expanding to add other functions, again signals-free because I couldn't make it work!). By the way, thanks for the 'dobbia' correction, I didn't expect to find such a great help so near home (I'm from Milano). Thanks a lot @musicamante, you seriously saved me!

Comment: @FabioCricelli Di niente! Well, I'm actually from Tokyo, that's why I'm here right now (kidding, I'm in Como, but we do share the same "mind-time-zone" :-D ). I suggest you to take your time to read all the references linked above; if you still have issues with signals, consider studying related resources/tutorials (the zetcode.com ones are normally well written, but also check what listed in the [related python wiki](//wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt/Tutorials)). Be aware, dealing with dates/times is a real nightmare. If you're doing that for a job, I don't envy you. (I'd say "che culo..." :-P )